# Pass dictionary as a argument to csv write function in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I want to append data into multiple columns of a csv file at a time.

I have defined a function "writeCSV" for it which is taking col_name and col_value to append in csv file.

```
def writeCSV(col_name,col_data):

    with open('COMPONENT_DETAILS.csv',"a") as COMPONENT_DETAILS_file:

        fieldnames = ['ID','module_name','module_id','tech_name','component_name','connecion','counter','connection_type']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(COMPONENT_DETAILS_file,fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writerow({col_name:col_data})
```

Now, suppose I want to append data into columns- tech_name, component_name,connection_type, how should I pass the argument to writeCSV() function? Would dictionary be helpful here?

Right now, I can only append to only one column by calling function with below syntax,

```
writeCSV('tech_name': 'Python')
```

Comment: "Right now, I can only append to only one column by calling function with below syntax," You cannot, that is invalid syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose and use of \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs)

Comment: oh yeah..actually I was calling it with,

writeCSV('tech_name','Python')

Thanks for your reply MisterMiyagi!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def writeCSV(dictionary):
        ##Your code
        csv_writer.writerow(dictionary)

writeCSV({'tech_name': 'Python2','component_name': 'Python3'})
```

This should do your work.As you have defined a **DictWriter** for writing to csv, you will have no problem in implementing this method.